# which element are sent by OpenMP parallel for?

Tags: c++, for-loop, parallel-processing, openmp, parallel.for

I am a new programmer in OpenMP. I want to process my data parallelly and I use OpenMP. How can I get which element were processed in for loop when I use it with OpenMP parallel for? For example:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    myFunc(i);
}
```

I do not want to send 1, 3, 6 together or 2 4 7 together. Can I manage which numbers are sent together?

Comment: OpenMP scheduling pragmas: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/openmp-loop-scheduling

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "sent together". OpenMP has no concept of sending anything (at least not in the context of parallel loops). Do you mean "executed concurrently"?

Comment: Yes I mean "executed concurrently". Sorry for my bad English. @JimCownie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read about chunk size as maybe it can help you [Scheduling examples](http://jakascorner.com/blog/2016/06/omp-for-scheduling.html)

For example if you will be good with taking 1,2 and 3,4 and 5,6 and so on you can do this simply by this code:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static, 2) 
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    myFunc(i);
}
```

This `schedule(static, 2)`  means that each thread will take 2 continues numbers like this:

- Thread 1 : 1,2
- Thread 2 : 3,4
- Thread 3 : 5,6

And so on until there is no more data. If you want different scheduling take a look at link at the beginning of the post. But note that some of them may come with some additional overhead.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I do not know which numbers can not be sent together. It depends on another function. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: As far as I know it is probably not possible with just OpenMP scheduling, but you can construct some tabel with indicies which can be executet together and then use it with OpenMP. 
Something like tab[10] = [1,4,6,3,5,7....] where number inside are grouped by their ability to be executed in parallel. I don't know fully your use case so I cannot sugest you any code.

Comment: So thank you, I will try it according to your explanation.